# Drawing coloured balls from an urn

Tags: probability, combinatorics

An urn contains 36 white, 1 red, 1 black, 1 green and 1 yellow ball. We draw one hundred balls with replacement. What is the probability that all of non-white balls will be drawn (each of them at least one time)?

What I thought to be the correct solution: first choose which $k$ of hundred drawn balls will be non-white, then count the surjections from $\{1, 2, 3, \dots, k-1, k\}$ into $\{R, B, G, Y\}$ (using Stirling numbers) and multiply it with appropriate probability (here $p = 4 / 40 = 1/10$).

Unfortunately, the result is terribly wrong:

$$\sum_{k=4}^{100} {100 \choose k} \cdot S_2(k,4) \cdot p^k \cdot (1-p)^{100-k} \approx 10^{11}$$

Do I count some results of the experiment multiple times?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would count the event (all colors drawn) using inclusion-exclusion:

$$40^{100}-4\cdot 39^{100}+6\cdot 38^{100}-4\cdot 37^{100}+36^{100}$$
Then divide by $40^{100}$ to get the desired probability. (It appears to be approximately $0.7158$)